# Calling this.callParent inside of Ext.js store.each

Tags: extjs

I have a Sencha class that extends Ext.draw.Component and it accepts a store of MyModel. I am trying two different methods and I am getting differing, non-satisfactory results.

**The First Method**
Inside the constructor of the class I read in the store and do the following:

```
//Inside constructor of the class
this.store = config.store; //config is passed in from the constructor
var me = this;
me.store.each(function (model) {
    me.renderTo = model.get('elementToRenderTo');
    me.items = [{
        type: 'rect',
        x: 1.6620979,
        y: 52.362183,
        radius: 90,
        width: 448.10959,
        height: 1000,
        fill: model.get('color'),
        stroke: 'none'    
    }];

    if (me.items) {
        Ext.apply(config, { //config is passed in from the constructor
            items: me.items
        });
    }

    me.callParent([config]);
}
```

When I put the last of the code where it is (inside of the store.each), I get an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

**The Second Method**
However, if I move the Ext.apply and callParent outside of the store.each, I don't get an expection, but only the last model gets drawn (likely because the me.items is being overwritten on each iteration of the model).

```
//Inside constructor of the class
this.store = config.store; //config is passed in from the constructor
var me = this;
me.store.each(function (model) {
    me.renderTo = model.get('elementToRenderTo');
    me.items = [{
        type: 'rect',
        x: 1.6620979,
        y: 52.362183,
        radius: 90,
        width: 448.10959,
        height: 1000,
        fill: 'black',
        stroke: 'none'    
    }];
}

if (me.items) {
    Ext.apply(config, { //config is passed in from the constructor
        items: me.items
    });
}

me.callParent([config]);
```

Is there another way to create a custom Ext.draw.Component that uses a store? What am I missing? The second method doesn't seem right, but I can't get rid of the exception on the first.

Comment: Your logic doesn't really make sense. You're looping over each record, but in the end you're just changing a property on the outer class, so it will always be equal to the list thing in the store.

Comment: I get that with the second method. But on the first method, I would expect it to draw the first model, then the second, and so on.

Comment: It does, but "me" never changes, so all the assignments you're doing are redundant until the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible issues with this code:

### 1

```
this.store = config.store;
```

Is this the store instance or a string config? The proper way to deal with store configs in a constructor is like so:

```
this.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store || 'ext-empty-store');
```

### 2

Although you are using `me` for scope, you probably want to ensure that the scope of `each` is indeed that of what's outside it so:

```
me.store.each(function (model) { ... }, this);
```

### 3

Regardless of where you do this, you won't be pushing all of the items:

```
Ext.apply(config, {
    items: me.items
});
```

Because what you do here is you keep override `item` with `me.items`.

You shouldn't apply anything to items - it's an array managed by the component itself. You should really add items to it instead:

```
items.push( me.items )
```

### 4

Are you assuming local store only? Because if your store is to be loaded asynchronously - you'd get nothing unless you load the items upon load.

### 5

What are you actually trying to do here? Have the items loaded from a store? If such is the case you shouldn't do it in the constructor.

You should really look at one of the Ext source files to see how this is to be done. Here's a simplified version of how [Ext.panel.Table](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Table.html#Ext-panel-Table) does it:

```
Ext.define('Ext.panel.Table', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me          = this,
            store       = me.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(me.store || 'ext-empty-store');

        me.mon(store, {
            load: me.onStoreLoad,
            scope: me
        });
    },

    onStoreLoad: function() {
    }
});
```

Comment: To answer number 6 - Yes, I am trying to have the items load from the store that is provided when creating the object. If the constructor isn't the right place, where is the right place to do?

Comment: To clarify, I am not adding items from the store, but rather populating the items with information from the store (like colors and stuff).

Comment: I really think you should do it using [sprite.setAttributes](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite-method-setAttributes) then.

Comment: Really? Can you manipulate colors and text through setAttributes? It seems like it is only available for Translation, Rotation, and Scaling.

Comment: The docs only give examples for these 3, but if you look at the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Sprite2.html#Ext-draw-Sprite-method-setAttributes) you'll see it is not limited to these.